# MSMQ (COM) Check if private queue exists

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-7, msmq

Ho can I check if a **private** queue exists on my PC using MSMQ COM Component in Delphi7, having path or format name?
I read about [`LookupQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it seems it's OK only for public queues and there I need a GUID which I do not know. Any other alternative or properly using of `LookupQueue` example are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is some piece of code which I used a while ago.

```
function GetAllPrivateQueues( const aMachine : WideString; aStrL : TStrings) : HRESULT;
// Returns a list of all private queues of a given machine
type PPWideChar = ^PWideChar;
var props : MQMGMTPROPS;
    keys  : array[0..0] of MGMTPROPID;
    vals  : array[0..0] of MQPROPVARIANT;
    ppws  : PPWideChar;
    i     : Integer;
begin
  // Init Props
  props.cProp    := 0;
  props.aPropID  := @keys;
  props.aPropVar := @vals;
  props.aStatus  := nil;

  // we want private queues
  ASSERT( props.cProp < (SizeOf(keys) / SizeOf(PROPID)));
  keys[props.cProp]         := PROPID_MGMT_MSMQ_PRIVATEQ;
  vals[props.cProp].vt      := VT_NULL;
  Inc(props.cProp);

  // MQMgmtGetInfo() has what we want, requires MSMQ 3.0
  result := MQMgmtGetInfo( PWideChar(aMachine), MO_MACHINE_TOKEN, props);
  if FAILED(result) then Exit;

  // collect the names
  // cast required this way, the data type in ActiveX.pas (D7) is incorrect
  ppws := PPWideChar(vals[0].calpwstr.pElems);
  for i := 0 to vals[0].calpwstr.cElems-1 do begin
    aStrL.Add( ppws^);
    MQFreeMemory( ppws^);
    Inc(ppws);
  end;
end;
```

Note that it may require some tweaking, depending on your exact environment and/or Delphi version. I did the windows header translations on my own, since I (also) needed it for D7 at that time. The header files are available in the Windows SDK, the relevant starting point is `mq.h`.